# Binomial Identity/Coefficient Question

Tags: binomial-coefficients

So I know that the coefficient of $[x^n]$ is computed by using:

$\left( \sum_{j=0}^n a_j b_{n-j} \right)$ = $[x^n]A(x)B(x)$

How is this formula used to make computations, for example, how do I compute:

$[x^7](1+x)^{20}$ ?

Comment: The index of the sum should be $j$ not $k$.

Comment: My bad, that was a typo, fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take $A(x)=(1+x)^{10}$ which implies $B(x)=A(x)=(1+x)^{10}$.

**Added:** From the identity, I gave in the note, you can see that

> $$ a_j = {10\choose j},\quad b_j=a_j={10\choose j}, $$

which gives

> $$ [x^7]A^2(x) = \sum_{j=0}^{7} {10\choose j}  {10\choose 7-j}=\dots\,. $$

**Note:** You need the identity

> $$ (1+x)^m = \sum_{i=0}^{m} {m\choose i}x^i. $$

Comment: I was confused at what a_j and b_j were, thank you so much I got it now

Comment: @user131570: You are very welcome.